# How to sort groups within a PROC SQL statement

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

In my proc sql statement I am grouping by ID's in the dataset. Each of these ID's may have one or more application dates associated to it. I would like the application dates to be grouped by the ID, but have the dates appear in ascending order. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show your code, tables and sample data

Answer (score 1):

Sort it by `group, date`. SAS will handle remerging the data automatically. Depending on how your data is structured, you may need to use `select distinct`.

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select distinct 
               regionName 
             , date
             , sum(sale) as sum_sale
        from sashelp.pricedata
        group by regionName
        order by regionName, date
    ;
quit;
```

You'll see in the log:

`NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data.`

This is SAS automatically doing the following for you:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select distinct 
               t1.regionName
             , t1.date
             , t2.sum_sale
        from sashelp.priceData as t1
        LEFT JOIN
             (select regionName, sum(sale) as sum_sale
              from sashelp.pricedata
              group by regionName
             ) as t2
        ON t1.regionName = t2.regionName 
        order by regionName, date
    ;
quit;
```